# Promise return from catch with Axios and final-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise, react-final-form

I am login in an api service from a React client with Axios. The form for name and password is handled by `final-form`. Everything works as expected, except when I want to return the error from the `onSubmit` function.

There are two components: a parent `Login`, which handles the call to the API with a `logIn` function, and a nested component `LoginUi`, which has the form and a `onSubmit` function, which calls the parent method `logIn` via `this.props.logIn()`:

Here the method `logIn` in the parent `Login` component:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
    }

    logIn(credentials) {
        return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/v1/login/',
            data: {
                name: credentials.name,
                password: credentials.password,
            },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return error;
            });
    }

    render() {
        return <LoginUi logIn={this.logIn} {...this.props} />;
    }
}

export default Login;
```

And here the method `onSubmit` in the child `LoginUi` component:

```
class LoginUi extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(credentials) {
        this.props
            .logIn(credentials)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);

                return { [FORM_ERROR]: 'Login Failed' };
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="LoginUi">
                {/* here goes the form with final-form, not included for brevity */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginUi;
```

`{ [FORM_ERROR]: 'Login Failed' }` is in charge of changing the state of the form —handled by `final-form`—, but it fails to do so. If I return it outside `catch` it works:

```
onSubmit(credentials) {
    this.props
        .logIn(credentials)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    return { [FORM_ERROR]: 'Login Failed' };
}
```

But obviously that's not what I want, because `[FORM_ERROR]: 'Login Failed'` must be returned only when the API call returns an error.

I'm pretty sure is a problem with the use of promises here. If anyone has any idea I would be grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the use case to return? why don't you `setState` in catch?

Comment: how do you use/call `onSubmit`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are relying on Promises onSubmit should return a promise. Add `return` to onSubmit otherwise it returns undefined and `final-form` has no way of knowing that the axios call was complete:

```
onSubmit(credentials) {
  return this.props
    .logIn(credentials)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);    
      return { [FORM_ERROR]: 'Login Failed' };
    });
}
```

Comment: An Event-handler, indicated by the `on` at the beginning, should not return anything. imo the OP should update the state inside the callbacks passed to `then` and `catch`.

Comment: @Thomas Based on the [doc](https://github.com/final-form/final-form#getting-started) onSubmit can be used by `final-form` directly via `createForm` call. In that case explicit setState calls are not required. I think that's the whole point of using `final-form`.

Comment: Actually, Final Form provides a way to return errors via a callback, rather than a promise, if you'd like. The third parameter given to your onSubmit function is a callback function.
https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#onsubmit-values-object-form-formapi-callback-errors-object--void--object--promiseobject--void